# Parameter between Ionic3 pages

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2, ionic3

I have a simple page with a user name. This user has a button with his id, when click we go to another page showing more details about this user. The problem is i can´t do pass params to the second page.

I have this code in first page.

```
export class VisitasPage {
  public data: any;
  public data2: any;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public visitas: VisitasServiceProvider) {
    this.verVisitas();
  }

  verVisitas(){
    this.visitas.Visitas()
    .then(data => {
      this.data = data;
    });
  }

  verDetalles(id:any){
    this.visitas.verVisita(id)
    .then(data2 => {
      this.data2 = Array(data2);
    });
    this.navCtrl.push(DatosPage, {
      animate: true,
      data:this.data2
    });
  }
```

When I put {{data}} in the second page console.log() show undefined and supposed to have an array. ¿Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't how are you trying to get that value in the *details* page, but the correct way to send and receive data from one page is like you can see in **[this stackblitz project](https://stackblitz.com/edit/nav-param-demo)**.

**HomePage**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { DetailsPage } from '../../pages/details/details';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {

  public ids = [1,2,3,4,5];

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {}

  public onOpenDetails(): void {
    this.navCtrl.push(DetailsPage, { data: this.ids});
  }

}
```

**DetailsPage**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-details',
  templateUrl: 'details.html'
})
export class DetailsPage {

  public dataIds: Array<number>;

  constructor(public navParams: NavParams) {
    this.dataIds = this.navParams.get('data');
  }

}
```

Comment: The problem it isn't a integer or string, i try to send an array to the second page. I don´t know exactly how send this type of data.

Comment: It's exactly the same, it doesn't matter the type of the parameter. Please take a look at the stackblitz project, I've updated the code to send and receive and array of numbers. @ElHombreSinNombre